# Android Studio indexing after every letter typed

Tags: android

Android Studio run indexing after every change to project (type letter, delete letter etc.), that makes hints unavailable. Invalidate cache/restart helping, but when i run app this problem returns. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Deliting folder with settings helped. It locates Users\User.AndroidStudio(version). But it is better to backup it thou.